# Searchview with back button

Tags: android, android-layout, searchview

I'm implementing searchview without Actionbar and toolbar. Everything is fixed, just back button remains. Below is my xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    <SearchView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"">
    </SearchView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I got something like this.

[image]

Below is the image what I need.

[image]

Any help would be great.

Comment: Instead of adding in layout add **android.support.v7.widget.SearchView** in the menu it will work fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView`

> Create a menu file like this in **`res/menu`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_search_album"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:title="@string/str_search_album"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|always" />

</menu>
```

> Create a **`searchable.xml`** file like this in `res/xml`

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="@string/search" >
</searchable>
```

> now in your activity you need to Override **`onCreateOptionsMenu()`** method

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

> Now in your manifest file

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>

    </activity>
```

for more information [android.support.v7.widget.SearchView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html)

Also check [How to create search interface](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html)

Comment: @MladenRakonjac sorry for the late reply but i have tested in API 28 and its working finr for me can u please explain what issue you are facing and please check updated answer

Comment: @MladenRakonjac Glad to have been of help!

Answer (score 1):

For API 21+ you can use `android:searchIcon="[your drawable here]"`.

Comment: This works great but when I club it with `app:closeIcon` then only the close icon shows but not the search icon. Is there a way out for this?