# Customization Search View Toolbar Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, toolbar

I want to make custom search bar layout in `android`. I have to attach screenshot of my design what I want to require. Check action bar design. On click action-bar search icon open custom edit-text in `toolbar`.

I want to make action bar layout like this.

[image: Show Design]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46085854/searchview-with-back-button/46087764#46087764

Comment: @NileshRathod these is not search view with back button issue.

Comment: @NileshRathod if you don't understand question then check what I am saying.

Comment: Have u check that answer its same

Comment: My question is not that, my question is how to use custom search view not back button, On click search icon open custom search view that views like above image

Comment: fine check the updated duplicates links

Answer (score 0):

Try this way make sure you have search icon..

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llSearchContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/drawer_gredient"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.80"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_search_box"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_2sdp"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/_2sdp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_24sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_24sdp"
                    android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_seach" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/lsfEtSearch"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.80"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:hint="Search"
                    android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:maxLength="50"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: But I want these search-view in action-bar.

Comment: not making custom then only define search view remove imageview or edittext

Comment: Please give me any example for these type of search view,

Comment: give link @Nilesh for comment section

Comment: I want search view custom not solving back arrow in toolbar, that working well, If you have update regarding custom search layout on click menu search icon then provide that link.